# Show Brownian Motion paths increasing has probability $\neq$ 1

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Essentially, we are to show then that 
$$ P(\{\omega:t\to B_t(\omega) \uparrow \})<1$$

How can I start with this? Supposedly the proof is just one line, I'm just not too sure what to apply here. Each independent increment must be increasing and therefore each $B_t − B_{t+1}$ > 0, which has probability $lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{1}{2^t} = 0$?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by increasing?

Comment: @LorenzoNajt $\{\omega:t\to B_t(\omega) \quad \text{is increasing} \}$ is the information I've been given. I guess it means each increment increases, which makes sense not to be equal to one if it is stochastic

Comment: I think you have the right idea.

Comment: But I have a strict $P= 0$, I wonder if I am missing something to get something more general where $P<1$, so I'm not sure it is correct

Comment: What about your argument is giving you doubts? Perhaps try writing it up formally as an answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

$P(B_{n+1}-B_n \geq 0 \, \forall n) =\lim_N P(B_{n+1}-B_n \geq 0 \,  \text {for} \, 1\leq n \leq N)=\lim_N [P(B_1-B_0 \geq 0)]^{N}=\lim_N \frac  1 {2^{N}} =0$.

I have used the following:

$B_{n+1}-B_n, n=1,2...$ are i.i.d. with $N(0,1)$ distribution and $P(X\geq 0)=\frac1  2$ if $X \sim N(0,1)$.

Comment: Show that $\Bbb P[B_1<B_2>B_3]>0$.

Comment: @JohnDawkins $P(B_1<B_2, B_2 >B_3)=P(B_2-B_1 >0, B_3-B_2 <0)=P(B_2-B_1 >0)P( B_3-B_2 <0)=\frac  1 4$.